# Convenient time string parsing in python

Tags: python, parsing, elasticsearch

I need to calculate the duration from a specific date to now for elasticsearch index cleaning.
My job will run in python. 
I have a configuration file:

```
indices:
  - name: test
    template: raw*
    liveLength: 1d
```

How to parse string "1d" or "2m" to a valid time interval for calculating duration from a specific date from liveLength field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to extract the number/time unit parts and then look up a multiplier in a dictionary. This way, it is a bit shorter and probably a whole lot more readable than [your](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54905197/1639625) manual parsing and `if/elif` chain.

```
>>> mult = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 60*60, "d": 60*60*24}
>>> s = "2d 4h 13m 5.2s"
>>> re.findall(r"(\d+(?:\.\d)?)([smhd])", s)
[('2', 'd'), ('4', 'h'), ('3', 'm'), ('5.2', 's')]
>>> sum(float(x) * mult[m] for x, m in _)
187385.2
```

As a function:

```
def duration(string):
    mult = {"s": 1, "m": 60, "h": 60*60, "d": 60*60*24}
    parts = re.findall(r"(\d+(?:\.\d)?)([smhd])", string)
    total_seconds = sum(float(x) * mult[m] for x, m in parts)
    return timedelta(seconds=total_seconds)

print(duration("2d 4h 13m 5.2s"))
# 2 days, 4:13:05.200000
```

This will also ensure that the number part is actually a valid number (and not just any sequence of digits and dots). Also, it will raise an exception if any other than the allowed time units are used.

The function could be further optimized by pre-compiling the regex with `re.compile` outside of the function. When I tested it with IPython's `%timeit`, mine showed to be a bit faster (2.1µs vs. 2.8µs for yours, both without the `timedelta` creation and with just `float` instead of `Decimal`). Also, I would consider this to be more readable by having a much more *declarative* and less *imperative* style, but that's certainly a matter of taste and preferences.

Comment: How we can compile some benchmark? For me code I found is more readable.

Comment: @ozlevka Really? Well, I guess it depends on how comfortable you are with dict comprehensions, generator expression, and, of course, regular expressions. In the end, you should take whatever you can work with best. But note, e.g., that your code also would consider `...2.3..4.5` a valid number... but if you know where the input is coming from that does not have to be a problem.

Comment: @ozlevka Since you asked for a benchmark: IPython's `%timeit` shows mine to be slightly faster (3.2µs vs. 4.6µs), but that seems to be largely due to your use of `Decimal`, which is probably not needed (you convert back to `float` anyway). Without `Decimal`, it's 3.2µs vs. 3.5µs.

Comment: Your code run average in 0.001150 ms if I compile regex before then run on average about 0.000900 ms. Direct parse also runs in average 0.000900 ms. Then performance is the same. But anyway I think that code should be readable for many people and not take time to understand.

Comment: @ozlevka I absolutely agree with you, readability is more important than micro-optimizing performance. I just consider my code actually more readable, as it's more explizit how the parts are supposed to look (using the regex instead of being spread up over many lines of loop and if/elif) and how they are summed. But again, you have to pick what you can work best with. Just trying to suggest an alternative.

Comment: I agree with you about a count of strings. And code quality. More from this I can admit that your code is more elegant and short. But I need to explain that code does for my customers. And  your solution make this task impossible :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the code on GitHub:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
from datetime import timedelta


def duration(duration_string): #example: '5d3h2m1s'
    duration_string = duration_string.lower()
    total_seconds = Decimal('0')
    prev_num = []
    for character in duration_string:
        if character.isalpha():
            if prev_num:
                num = Decimal(''.join(prev_num))
                if character == 'd':
                    total_seconds += num * 60 * 60 * 24
                elif character == 'h':
                    total_seconds += num * 60 * 60
                elif character == 'm':
                    total_seconds += num * 60
                elif character == 's':
                    total_seconds += num
                prev_num = []
        elif character.isnumeric() or character == '.':
            prev_num.append(character)
    return timedelta(seconds=float(total_seconds))
```

Very good [example](https://gist.github.com/Ayehavgunne/ac6108fa8740c325892b)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution; I used the python `datetime` library and it's `timedelta`:

```
import datetime

intervals = {
    "w": datetime.timedelta(weeks=1),
    "d": datetime.timedelta(days=1),
    "h": datetime.timedelta(hours=1),
    "m": datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
    "s": datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
    }

def parse_live_length(string):
    time_interval_start_index = 0

    for char in string:
        if char.isnumeric():
            time_interval_start_index += 1
        else:
            return int(string[0:time_interval_start_index]), string[time_interval_start_index:]

    return False

# "2w" used as an example
live_length = "2w"
time_scalar, ll_interval = parse_live_length(live_length)

for interval in intervals:
    if interval == ll_interval:
        new_delta = time_scalar * intervals[interval]
        break 

# Example of how it could be used
current = datetime.datetime.now()
new_time = new_delta + current
print(new_time.day, new_time.month, new_time.year)
```